# Integrated windows authentication to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception, ado.net, windows-authentication

I have an application that uses a database on SQL Server and I want users to connect to that server using integrated windows authentication. The connection string is:

```
SqlConnection scn = new SqlConnection("Data Source='server name';Initial Catalog=temp;Trusted_Connection=true;Integrated Security=SSPI");
```

When I run the application from my pc it works just fine and it recognizes my user name. But when I run it from the server then it gives me the following error:

> Login failed for user 'domain\server Name$'.

As I understand it doesn't recognize the user name and thinks that the user name is the server name.

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application correctly connects as the server machine account. Processes running as `LocalSystem` or as `Network Service` authenticate over the network as the machine, `domain\machine$`, this is by design, intentional and desired.

You can grant `domain\server$` login rights into SQL as needed. Or you can change the application to run under a different account (I assume the application is a service?).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`runas`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) to have the application run with the correct credentials.